# Fetch one value out of two from an array

Tags: php, arrays, facebook-graph-api

I have an array of which I want to make a exception while fetching the data out of it. below is the array -

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(15) "578" [1]=> string(15) "168" } 
array(2) { [0]=> string(15) "533" [1]=> string(15) "578" } 
array(2) { [0]=> string(15) "024" [1]=> string(15) "578" } 
array(2) { [0]=> string(15) "307" [1]=> string(15) "578" } 
array(2) { [0]=> string(15) "578" [1]=> string(15) "983" } 
array(2) { [0]=> string(15) "578" [1]=> string(15) "155" } 
array(2) { [0]=> string(15) "380" [1]=> string(15) "578" } 
array(2) { [0]=> string(15) "862" [1]=> string(15) "578" }
```

Now from the these array sets I want to get value ONLY EXCEPT the value '578'. Any idea how this can be done ? Thank you.

Comment: Can you show what the result data would look like. Is it one array of all unique values except 578?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add both values and substract 578! Voilà!